# Infobox for map onload.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I have a google map with marker and info box with information about location will come when user click the map. I gave event onclick to create infobox that way. Now I need infobox to be loaded initially when map is loaded not onclick. I wrote a code which is not loading.Please need assistance.

```
$scope.map = {
            center: {
                latitude: 0,
                longitude: 0
            },
            zoom: 1,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            control: {}
        };

        // place a marker
        $scope.markers = [];

        function setMarker(lat, long, title, content) {
            var marker = {
                id: $scope.markers.length+1,
                coords: {
                    latitude: lat,
                    longitude: long
                },
                options: {
                    title: title,
                    icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'
                },
                events: {
                    click: function(marker, eventName, args) {
                        // close window if not undefined
                        var infoWindow;
                        if (infoWindow !== void 0) {
                            infoWindow.close();
                        }
                        // create new window
                        var infoWindowOptions = {
                            content: content
                        };
                        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions);
                        infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
                    }
                }
            };
            $scope.markers.push(marker);
        };
```

My new code for on onload map comes as follows , I replaced this code in place on click event.

```
window.onload = function(e){ 

 var infoWindow;
if (infoWindow !== void 0) {
    infoWindow.close();
}
// create new window
var infoWindowOptions = {
    content: content
};
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions);
infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
```

}

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow,

Comment: you have to handle the map load event not the window onload event.

Comment: Hi I even tried that. but still no luck..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example (modified version of [Info windows sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple)) demonstrates how to open info window *once the map is loaded*

```js
angular.module('mapApp', [])

    .controller('mapCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: { lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044 },
            zoom: 4
        });


        var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
            '<div id="siteNotice">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
            '<div id="bodyContent">'+
            '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
            'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
            'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
            'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
            '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
            'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
            'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
            'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
            'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
            'Heritage Site.</p>'+
            '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
            'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
            '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>';

        $scope.infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: contentString
        });
        
        $scope.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044},
          map: $scope.map,
          title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
        });
        $scope.marker.addListener('click', function() {
          $scope.infoWindow.open($scope.map, $scope.marker);
        });
        $scope.infoWindow.open($scope.map,$scope.marker); 
        


    }]);
```

```css
#map 
{
    height: 480px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mapApp"  ng-controller="mapCtrl" >
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi , I created the click even infobox already in my code. I just need onload, like when map is loaded i need the infobox

Comment: @NicoletaWilskon, in the provided example the info window is getting displayed once the map is loaded (there is a button "Run the code" at the bottom of the answer that demonstrates it)